# Greenlet not installing to lib directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, google-cloud-platform, greenlets

I'm trying to deploy my app to Google Cloud Platform, which requires me to install all dependencies in the project directory. To do so, I ran `pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt`, but it didn't work for some of the modules. For example, `gevent` is installed in the `lib` directory (there is a subdirectory `lib/gevent`), but `greenlet` is not. The only subdirectory that I get is `lib/greenlet-0.4.13.dist-info`, and there is a file `lib/greenlet.pyd`. As a result, the Cloud Platform is not detecting `greenlet`, and I get an import error. I have tried uninstalling it and installing manually using `pip install -t lib greenlet`, but I get the same result. How do I get it to install properly?

Comment: Which version was listed in the requirements.txt file? And what is under the greenlet-0.4.13.dist-info folder? Which version was used for your application? You could also share the requirements.txt file with us.

Comment: Also, if you experience an error with the deployment, do share the full error. It may be helpful.